# Trouble on using the RSpec 'its' feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9, RSpec-rails 2 and FactoryGirl. I am trying to use the RSpec `its` feature on a association model (in the following example it is `:account`) but I have some trouble.

In my spec file I have:

```
describe User do
  describe "Associations" do
    let(:user) { Factory(:user, :account => Factory.build(:users_account)) }

    it { should respond_to(:account) }  # This work correctly

    its(:account) { should_not be_nil } # This does NOT work correctly (read below for more information)
  end
end
```

If I run the above code I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: its(:account) { should_not be_nil }
  expected: not nil
    got: nil
```

**How can I make the above code to work so to correctly use the RSpec `its` feature?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a ')' after (:users_account).

Beyond that I'm not sure, but you could try to use subject instead of let as in,

```
 subject { Factory.build(:user, :account => Factory.build(:users_account)) }
```

Comment: you could use the `let` too, but with a subject: `subject { user }`

Comment: @Iain - "you could use the let too, but with a subject..." - Can you make a complete example using let?

Comment: @user502052 Lain just meant to use `let` as the original asker did: `let(:user) {...}` then do a `subject {user}` after.